# how to resolve AccessViolationException

Tags: access-violation

Could you please help in resolving the below mentioned issue:

Following are the code snippet:

Managed code (VC++) - wrapper code:

Method-1:

```
void displayString(std::string abc)
{
  std::string xyz=abc;
  std::cout<<xyz;
}
```

Method-2:

```
void sendData(System::String^ input)
{
  char* inputData = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(input).ToPointer();
  std::string argData = inputData;
  displayString(argData); //Working fine

 //passing string instance to unmanaged code 
 /* while execution the below line the system throws: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData), _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse), HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED, and finally AccessViolationException */

   sendDisplayString(argData); //AccessViolationException 
   sendDisplayString("Hello"); //AccessViolationException

}
```

unmanaged code C++ dll:

```
void sendDisplayString(std::string input)
{
  std::cout<<input;
}
```

Note: Searched in all provided link but there is no resolution for this issue. All the links route to MSDN marshalling page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it answers your question: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172396

Comment: Thank you very much Kan, I am trying to under the things. If you have seen the same issue earlier and provided the resolution for it, that helps me a lot.

Comment: You should have pure-C interface between DLLs.